# Problem with installing frida module (frida-il2cpp-bridge) and make it running

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, frida

1 - I have installed **frida with python**.

2 - Then I download frida-il2cpp-bridge and use `npm install --save-dev frida-il2cpp-bridge`.

3 - I create js script

```
import "frida-il2cpp-bridge";

console.log("Script loaded successfully ..... ");

async function main() {
    await Il2Cpp.initialize();
    const domain = await Il2Cpp.Domain.get();
    console.log("il2cpp loaded at ",domain);
}

main().catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
```

4 - I put **javascript file with frida-il2cpp-bridge.**

5 - I run frida with: `frida --no-pause -U -l ./frida-il2cpp-bridge.js -f com.example.app.`

But it gives this error text:

> Failed to load script: script(line 1): SyntaxError: expecting '('

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all install Node-v16*.exe and Git-2*.exe..
Create new folder anywhere you want (like D:\il2cpp-bridge)
Open command prompt from created folder and type

```
$ git clone https://github.com/oleavr/frida-agent-example.git
$ cd frida-agent-example/
$ npm install -g typescript
$ npm install
$ npm install --save-dev frida-il2cpp-bridge
$ npm run watch
```

Open index.ts file from agent folder and replace all text

```
import "frida-il2cpp-bridge";
console.log("Rebuilded")


Il2Cpp.perform(() => {
    
    Il2Cpp.dump().fileName("dump.cs").classes().build();        
    
});
```

*This script will dump your game

Done!
Now you can spawn your game with attached _agent.js like

```
frida -Uf com.example.app -l _agent.js --no-pause
```

P.S. Make sure that your cmd with "npm run watch" command allways still active. It will rebuild your _agent.js file every time you will modify your index.ts