# Problem with installing frida module (frida-il2cpp-bridge)

Tags: typescript, frida

here is a answers that how to install frida module (frida-il2cpp-bridge)

I follow the steps,but i met errors.

[Problem with installing frida module (frida-il2cpp-bridge) and make it running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69980349/problem-with-installing-frida-module-frida-il2cpp-bridge-and-make-it-running)

[install steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN5Dp.png)

my errors is

```
Spawned `com.games`. Resuming main thread!
ReferenceError: 'exports' is not defined
    at <anonymous> (/node_modules/frida-il2cpp-bridge/dist/index.js:2)
```

I even do other install, but no one works.

it seems like my tsconfig.json file "module": "commonjs" does not work.

after two days google search, i still can not solve it.can anyone help me?

extra info:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>node -v
v16.16.0

C:\Users\Administrator>npm -v
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
8.14.0
```

i also change typescript version. but it still not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be resolved by using lower version of frida-compile.

It seems there's a lot a of change in frida-compile how it compiles. So follow wiki guides and anyone who encounter this issue must check their package.json and check frida-compile's version is ^10.2.4 .